# Deploying Openstack without internet access on CentOS Server

Tags: centos, openstack

I want to deploy openstack on a CentOS server without internet access. I am really confused please help me if you know how I can do it.

These are a few options:

1. create a vm on another system with internet access and then transfer that vm to the server and boot it as the main OS of the server -- but I am not sure if it is possible or not
2. Install packages of openstack manually: really tedious and time consuming work to do specially on CentOS. I tried and two of the main packages of openstack were conflicting with each other.

I am looking for the best and of course practical option. Thank you in advance

Comment: So just to be clear, your server is already running CentOS (installed), correct? Can you move the server temporarily somewhere with internet access? Or provide a http_proxy? There several options, but some machine will have to have internet access, e. g. as a repository server or as a local container registry (for example for kolla-ansible deployment). You could install devstack all-in-one or kolla-ansible on a single host, but again, the server needs some sort of source for either images or packages. If I misunderstood your question, please clarify. Which deployment method are you aiming at?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. yes exactly I finally installed openstack by sharing internet with vlan cable from another pc. it is almost impossible to install it without internet access.

Comment: If you want to install updates on your host and openstack cloud you’ll need a solution for that as well. So it makes sense to consider having a proxy for internet access (or something like that) as a permanent solution.